# @param and @returns JSDoc description is not shown in auto-suggestion preview - VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript file with function having JSDoc Comments

```
   /**
     * Get the manipulated URL
     * @param  {string} inputURL URL received from web services
     * @returns {string} updated URL with extension
     */
    manipulateURL (inputURL:string) : string {
        //Logic to manipulate URL
     }
```

In another file when using this function only **Get the manipulated URL** displayed in auto-suggestion function preview. I was able to see `@author` in auto-suggestion preview. But `@param` and `@returns` are not being shown, are needed in most of functions.

Is there a way to configure preview of JSDoc to show `@returns` and `@param` in VS Code auto-suggestion preview?

**Additional Details**

1. VS Code version - 1.16.1
2. Node version - 8.11.2
3. OS - Windows 7

Comment: You should upgrade to latest version (currently 1.25.1). My editor can show the comment. You should upgrade typescript too

Comment: Thanks @hgiasac. That was it!. I couldn't upgrade due to admin restrictions on my machine. Requested my colleague to check and it worked. This is the correct answer to this specific question. If you could post, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to latest version (currently 1.25.1). My editor can show the comment. You should upgrade typescript too